# /usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdam1

Tags: software-raid, grub

When upgrading the kernel I get:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdam1.
Check your device.map.
Auto-detection of a filesystem of /dev/sdam1 failed.

Please report this together with the output of "/usr/sbin/grub-probe
--device-map=/boot/grub/device.map --target=fs -v /boot/grub" to
<bug-grub@gnu.org>
```

/dev/sdam is clearly (hd13). The rest of the drives are a software RAID60.

Can I force GRUB to install on /dev/sdam1 (hd13) without probing?

```
# grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 1.98+20100804-14+squeeze1


# stdout /usr/sbin/grub-probe --device-map=/boot/grub/device.map
--target=fs -v /boot/grub
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd0 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd0 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd1 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd1 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd2 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd2 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd3 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd3 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd4 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd4 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd5 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd5 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd6 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd6 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd7 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd7 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd8 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd8 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd9 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd9 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd10 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd10 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd11 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd11 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd12 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd12 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd13 is 140623872.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd13 is 140623872.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd13 is 140623872.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd14 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd14 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd15 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd15 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd16 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd16 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd17 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd17 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd18 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd18 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd19 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd19 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd20 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd20 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd21 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd21 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd22 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd22 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd23 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd23 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd24 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd24 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd25 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd25 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd26 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd26 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd27 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd27 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd28 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd28 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd29 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd29 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd30 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd30 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd31 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd31 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd32 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd32 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd33 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd33 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd34 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd34 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd35 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd35 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd36 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd36 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd37 is 5860533168.
error: found two disks with the number 0.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd37 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd38 is 5860533168.
error: found two disks with the number 0.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd38 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd39 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd39 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd40 is 5860533168.
error: found two disks with the number 0.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd40 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd41 is 5860533168.
error: found two disks with the number 0.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd41 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd42 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd42 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd43 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd43 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd44 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd44 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd45 is 5860533168.
error: superfluous RAID member (10 found).
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd45 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd0 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd0 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd1 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd1 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd2 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd2 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd3 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd3 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd4 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd4 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd5 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd5 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd6 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd6 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd7 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd7 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd8 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd8 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd9 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd9 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd10 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd10 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd11 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd11 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd12 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd12 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd13 is 140623872.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd13 is 140623872.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd13 is 140623872.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd14 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd14 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd15 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd15 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd16 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd16 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd17 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd17 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd18 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd18 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd19 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd19 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd20 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd20 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd21 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd21 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd22 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd22 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd23 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd23 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd24 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd24 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd25 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd25 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd26 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd26 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd27 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd27 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd28 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd28 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd29 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd29 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd30 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd30 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd31 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd31 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd32 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd32 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd33 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd33 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd34 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd34 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd35 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd35 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd36 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd36 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd37 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd37 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd38 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd38 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd39 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd39 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd40 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd40 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd41 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd41 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd42 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd42 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd43 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd43 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd44 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd44 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd45 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd45 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: changing current directory to /dev.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: changing current directory to md.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: changing current directory to dri.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: changing current directory to net.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: changing current directory to shm.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: /dev/sdam1 starts from 2048.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: opening the device hd0.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: info: the size of hd0 is 5860533168.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdam1.
Check your device.map.

# cat /boot/grub/device.map
(hd0)   /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_S1F080J6
(hd1)   /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD30EURS-63R8UY0_WD-WCAWZ2791776
(hd2)   /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_S1F07ER8
(hd3)   /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_S1F07ZS1
(hd4)   /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_S1F07WY3
(hd5)   /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_S1F03NQK
(hd6)   /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_S1F07VNN
(hd7)   /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_S1F07VNG
(hd8)   /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_W1F0B4FB
(hd9)   /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_S1F058B4
(hd10)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_S1F07ZQZ
(hd11)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_S1F07VFM
(hd12)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_W1F08VK8
(hd13)  /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-3600508e0000000000ebdff75febc5a02
(hd14)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_S1F07WRL
(hd15)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_S1F069HJ
(hd16)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_S1F07Y4B
(hd17)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_S1F05E68
(hd18)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_S1F0823X
(hd19)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_S1F0801D
(hd20)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_S1F07WQL
(hd21)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000VX000-9YW166_W1F0BX78
(hd22)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_S1F04AV3
(hd23)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_S1F00MLQ
(hd24)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_S1F082SY
(hd25)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_S1F07EFW
(hd26)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_S1F00LFZ
(hd27)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_S1F07F2R
(hd28)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_S1F02T6L
(hd29)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_S1F011WM
(hd30)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_W1F08Y40
(hd31)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_S1F00JTH
(hd32)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_S1F07W6S
(hd33)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_S1F04YGF
(hd34)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_S1F07RM1
(hd35)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_S1F00KPA
(hd36)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_W1F13EHX
(hd37)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_W1F15EME
(hd38)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_W1F15EA7
(hd39)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD30EZRS-11J99B1_WD-WMAWZ0393685
(hd40)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_W1F10LKZ
(hd41)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD30EZRX-00MMMB0_WD-WCAWZ2273685
(hd42)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_W1F0BGSY
(hd43)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_S1F0193V
(hd44)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_S1F07YBK
(hd45)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST33000651NS_Z292DJXW
```

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: Remove all the other devices (modprobe -r mpt2sas), then run again. The warning:

```
grub /usr/sbin/grub-probe: warn: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/sdam1
```

can be ignored.